# How to create pop up window for login page

Tags: users, javascript

I want something like if i click on the login then pop window should open where in i should able to enter my Id and password to login, as as of now i tried with modules like

[Fancy Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/fancy_login)

[Ajax Register](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register)

[Modal Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms)

above module i just installed and enabled.

But no luck can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @kashish did you enable the modal forms for login links?

Comment: @SaidYousafzai: yea i enabled

Answer (score 0):

1)use this module
https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms

2)create a block and put this code in it :

```
 <?php
global $user;
 global $base_url;
if($user->uid == '0')
{ 
?>
<a class="ctools-use-modal" href="<?php print $base_url; ?  >/modal_forms/nojs/login">Login</a>
 <?php
}
else
 {
 echo '<p><a href="'.$base_url.'/user/logout">Logout</a></p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: after putting this code in block...place the block in your region wherever u want